# Proving that $d(f,g)=\|f-g\| = \sup \limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |f(x)-g(x)|$ is a metric on $X=C_b[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

Following [Proving that $d(f,g)=\|f-g\| = \sup \limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |f(x)-g(x)|$ is a metric on $X=C[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322571/proving-that-df-g-f-g-sup-limits-0-leq-x-leq-1-fx-gx-is-a-m)

I would like to prove that the same is true for **bounded** functions on $[0,1]$ ,$C_b([0,1]) = \{f:X \to Y| f \text{ bounded }\}$ (not necessarily continuous), however I can't see where I could use the boundedness property. I am producing a proof that is essentially identical to the linked and that confuses me a little bit.

Proof attempt: Obvious  $d(f,g) = \sup \limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |f(x)-g(x)| \geq 0 $ and $d(f,g) = d(g,f)$.

Triangle inequality:

Let,$f,g,h$ be bounded functions, then

$f(x) - h(x) = f(x) - g(x) + g(x) - h(x) \leq |f(x) - g(x)| + |g(x) - h(x)| \leq \sup \limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |f(x)-g(x)| +  \sup \limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |g(x)-h(x)|$

Then taking $\sup$ over LHS yields $\sup \limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |f(x)-h(x)| \leq\sup \limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |f(x)-g(x)| +  \sup \limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |g(x)-h(x)|$

But no where in above proof did I use boundedness assumption. Can someone please point out where an adjustment could be made?

Thanks

Comment: The boundedness is needed to know that $d(f,g) < +\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need boundedness to be able to define the metric.

On the notation side, usually $C_b$ is reserved for "continuous and bounded". A more common notation (although not universal) would be $B(X)$.

Comment: I know, it is frustrating beyond words because $C_b$ is continuous and bounded everywhere other than the textbooks I am using. The textbook says $C_b$ is the space is bounded function and $C_0$ is the space of continuous and bounded function...so $C_0 \subset C_b$

Comment: Uh, that's seriously unusual.